# How to Try/Catch a Swift_TransportException in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, exception, closures, php-7, swiftmailer

My app launch an exception in Laravel 6:

[image]

In the screenshot, I add try/catch block, first with the Swift_TransportException and then with the generic Exception. In all the cases, the try block not work.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I think the problem comes from the side that it is a Clousere Function, and the Try/Catch not work from sequential way, but still don't fix it.